# Smallest eigenvalue (and associated eigenvector) of very large sparse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a very large matrix, $A$, which represents the (many-body) hamiltonian of a system of interacting electrons in a particular basis. The dimension of the matrix may be 50000x50000, 100000x100000 or even larger. The matrix, however, is sparse, with low density, because in my problem each quantum state is connected with at much twenty other states or so. To save memory, I stored this matrix as a sparse matrix, and I tried using [Lanczos' algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm) as implemented in the Matlab built-in function *eigs* to find the smallest eigenvalue. However, for matrices larger than 20000x20000 the algorithm does not converge after several hours.

What other useful strategies/algorithm are there to diagonalize such large matrices. Keep in mind that I'd only need the smallest eigenvalue and its eigenvector (the ground state).

Comment: Maybe largest eigenvalue of the inverse matrix could be computed? For example power method of some Krylov subspace method.

Comment: The problem is that the inverse matrix is not sparse, and even storing it is a huge problem. I believe that inverting such large matrices should be, in principle, avoided at all costs

Comment: Are you sure that you need the smallest eigenvalue (in absolute value)? A sparse matrix contains mostly zeros, so usually it is not of full rank. Or do you mean the largest eigenvalue in absolute value, which you know to be negative?

Comment: @Qwertuy you don't need to actually calculate and store it if you use Krylov methods.

Comment: @quarague I meant the smallest eigenvalue, not the smallest in absolute value. mathreadler: I'll look up your suggestion, thanks! that I have not tried

Comment: Smallest as in largest negative? Maybe you can search for $\min_v \|Mv - \lambda v\|_2^2$ for large negative $\lambda$.